# MDX Conditional/Dynamic Case Statement based on SSRS tuple parameter

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to build a case statement (or equivalent) in MDX query to group together dimensional members based on parameter input from SSRS?

Below is a query showing roughly what I am trying to achieve (parameters have been commented out and hardcoded for testing) I'm afraid that I'm fairly new to mdx;

```
WITH
--PERIOD FOR COMPARISON BLOCK
SET [MonthNumber] AS
(
STRTOSET("[Date Procurement Created].[Month Number].&[9]"
        --@DimCalendarMonthNumber
        , CONSTRAINED)
)
--CONDITIONAL CASE BLOCK
SET [SelectedSuppliers] AS

      CASE [Dim Supplier].[Supplier Name].CurrentMember
         WHEN STRTOSET("[Dim Supplier].[Supplier Name].&[Flannels Direct Co Ltd],[Dim Supplier].[Supplier Name].&[Zucchini Trading Co]"
        --@DimSupplierSupplierName
        , CONSTRAINED)

         THEN [Dim Supplier].[Supplier Name].CurrentMember

         ELSE 'Other'
      END

--CURRENT PERIOD BLOCK
MEMBER [Measures].[CP_LineTotal]
AS SUM(
([Measures].[Line Total],[MonthNumber])
),   FORMAT_STRING = 'Currency'

--MAIN QUERY BLOCK
SELECT {
[Measures].[Line Total]
, [Measures].[CP_LineTotal]

}
ON 0,

NON EMPTY (

[SelectedSuppliers]
*[Dim Supplier].[AC Number].[AC Number].MEMBERS
*[Date Procurement Created].[Year Name].[Year Name].MEMBERS

)
ON 1

FROM
[TRANSACTION_PROCUREMENT]
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve with the case statement. Describe the logic you want to apply i.e. If Currentmember is `xxx` then I want `xx,yy,zz` set

Answer (score 0):

I think this part of your code could change to the following:

```
SET [SelectedSuppliers] AS
      IIF( 
        [Dim Supplier].[Supplier Name].CurrentMember
         IS [Dim Supplier].[Supplier Name].&[Flannels Direct Co Ltd],[Dim Supplier].[Supplier Name].&[Zucchini Trading Co]
        ,[Dim Supplier].[Supplier Name].CurrentMember
        ,'Other'
      )
```

`IIF` should always be used rather than `CASE` if possible.
Use the `IS` operator to compare members.

Also no need to use `Sum` in your definition of the measure as a simple tuple will suffice:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[CP_LineTotal] AS 
([Measures].[Line Total],[MonthNumber])
,   FORMAT_STRING = 'Currency'
```